# Hacer tabla dinamica y estatica HTML y PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Llevo rato intentando sacar los datos del **PHP** desdes un **Js** y no encuentro manera. Pongo el ejemplo de uno de los **php** y  el **HTML** que me es imposible de recorrer.

Necesito optener datos de un archivo php donde obtengo los datos en PHP y los quiero poner en una tabla estaticas. solo quiero obtener algunos datos de la tabla de la base de datos **Mysql** ya que los otros datos no quieron que nunca se muevan de la tabla. lo que  busco es a;go asi como lo que tengo en la imagen de abajo, lo marcado con amarillo es lo que quiero que siempre se muestre lo mismo y los otros datos se muestran segun la informacion de la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CODIGO HTML**

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> STATION BSL</title>
   
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <script>
       

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "Get/GetHistory.php",
                dataType: "json",
               console.log(result);
                success: function(result) {

                    $.each(result, function(i, value) {
                        if (value[0] == "Version") {
                            document.getElementById("Version").innerHTML = value[1];
                        } else if (value[0] == "PIC") {
                            document.getElementById("PIC").innerHTML = value[2];
                        } else if (value[0] == "Turno") {
                            document.getElementById("Turno").innerHTML = value[3];
                        } else if (value[0] == "Comments") {
                            document.getElementById("Comments").innerHTML = value[4];
                        } else if (value[0] == "Update_Time") {
                            document.getElementById("Update_Time").innerHTML = value[5];
                        } else {
                            alert("Error en el Query");
                        }


                    });

                },
                error: function(jqXHR, status, err) {
                    alert(jqXHR.responseText);

                }

            });


        });
    </script>



    

</head>


<body>


    <!-- Cabecera -->
    <header>

        <div id="contenedor">
            <div id="cabecera">
                <h1>STATION BSL</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="menu">
                <div id="fondomenu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="Index.html">STATION BSL</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Station.html">HISTORY</a></li>
                        <li><a href="formulario.php">REGISTER DATA</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </header>

    <!-- Contenido -->
    <section>


        <center>
            <table class="grilla" id="tablajson">
                <thead>

                    <tr>
                        <th>Online Status</th>
                        <th>IP</th>
                        <th>Station name ID</th>
                        <th>Version</th>
                        <th>PIC</th>
                        <th>Turno</th>
                        <th>Comments</th>
                        <th>Update Time</th>
                        <th>Update Version</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td>10.49.</td>
                        <td>F4-198</td>
                        <td><label style="font-size:20px" id="Version"> </label> </td>
                        <td><label style="font-size:20px" id="PIC"> </label></td>
                        <td> <label style="font-size:20px" id="Turno"> </label></td>
                        <td> <label style="font-size:20px" id="Comments"> </label></td>
                        <td> <label style="font-size:20px" id="Update_Time"> </label></td>
                       
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td>10.49.</td>
                        <td>F4-199</td>
                        <td>21.3.9006.0 </td>
                        <td> <label style="font-size:20px" id="Version"> </label></td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                       
                    </tr>

                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </center>




    </section>


</body>

</html>
```

**CODIGO PHP**

```
<?php
//Creamos la conexión
$conn=mysqli_connect("IP","login","password","baseDatos");
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}
//generamos la consulta
$sql="SELECT* FROM `tbl_stacionbsl` ORDER BY Update_Time DESC LIMIT 8";


mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8"); //formato de datos utf8

if(!$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) die();
$clientes = array(); //creamos un array


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
 
    
    $Online_Status =$row['Online_Status'];
    $IP=$row['IP'];
    $name_ID=$row['Station_name_ID'];
    $Version=$row['Version'];
    $PIC=$row['PIC'];
    $Turno=$row['Turno'];
    $Comments=$row['Comments'];
    $Update_Time=$row['Update_Time'];
  
    
    $clientes[] = array('Online_Status'=> $Online_Status, 'IP'=> $IP, 'Station_name_ID'=> $name_ID, 'Version'=> $Version,
        'PIC'=> $PIC, 'Turno'=> $Turno, 'Comments'=> $Comments, 'Update_Time'=> $Update_Time,);
}
    


echo json_encode($clientes);
```

Comment: Porque no llamar los datos directamente en PHP e imprimirlos en HTML, no usando ajax?

Comment: eso como lo aria ?

Comment: Te dejo en las respuestas una opción a ver si te sirve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo no asignar los valores a label con id ya que el resultado puede ser más de un registro y al hacerlo de esa forma siempre te imprimirá un solo registro.

Te dejo el mismo ejemplo pero usando PHP y HTML embebido para que comprendas un poco el funcionamiento del recorrido de cada registro y asignarlo a una fila de la tabla.

***Por cierto, el archivo debes guardarlo con extensión .php***

```
<?php
    //Creamos la conexión
    $conn=mysqli_connect("IP","login","password","baseDatos");
    
    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    //generamos la consulta
    $sql="SELECT* FROM `tbl_stacionbsl` ORDER BY Update_Time DESC LIMIT 8";
    
    mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8"); //formato de datos utf8
    
    if(!$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) die(); 
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> STATION BSL</title>
        
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <!-- Cabecera -->
        <header>
            
            <div id="contenedor">
                <div id="cabecera">
                    <h1>STATION BSL</h1>
                </div>
                <div id="menu">
                    <div id="fondomenu">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="Index.html">STATION BSL</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Station.html">HISTORY</a></li>
                            <li><a href="formulario.php">REGISTER DATA</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </header>
        
        <!-- Contenido -->
        <section>
            
            <center>
                <table class="grilla" id="tablajson">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Online Status</th>
                            <th>IP</th>
                            <th>Station name ID</th>
                            <th>Version</th>
                            <th>PIC</th>
                            <th>Turno</th>
                            <th>Comments</th>
                            <th>Update Time</th>
                            <th>Update Version</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    
                    <tbody>
                        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
                            <tr>                
                                <td> </td>
                                <td>10.49.</td>
                                <td>F4-198</td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['Version']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['PIC']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['Turno']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['Comments']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['Update_Time']; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                        
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </center>
            
        </section>
        
    </body>
</html>
```